# python sqlite3.connect - unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite

I am running Python3 on my Mac testing simple sql database. I have the below code

```
import sqlite3

# connecting to the database
connection = sqlite3.connect("myTable.db")
crsr = connection.cursor()

# SQL command to create a table in the database
sql_command = """CREATE TABLE emp (
staff_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
fname VARCHAR(20),
lname VARCHAR(30),
gender CHAR(1),
joining DATE);"""

# execute the statement
crsr.execute(sql_command)

# SQL command to insert the data in the table
sql_command = """INSERT INTO emp VALUES (23, "Rishabh", "Bansal", "M", "2014-03-28");"""
crsr.execute(sql_command)

crsr.execute(sql_command)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

When I run this code, I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    connection = sqlite3.connect("myTable.db")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What am I missing? I tried replacing `("myTable.db")` with `(".myTable.db")` and `("./myTable.db")` but same issue. Please suggest.

Comment: One possibility is that the Python process's current working directory is not what you expect. Try adding `print(os.getcwd())` to your script as a debugging aid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change permissions to SQLite db file.

#### Ubuntu

```
sudo chmod 775 /FolderOfSQLiteDBfile/
sudo chmod 664 /FolderOfSQLiteDBfile/sqlite.db
```

#### Windows

```
chmod 775 /FolderOfSQLiteDBfile/
```

Refer : [sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file](https://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: A database is a sensible thing. Make sure the permissions are set for minimal access. The permissions above allow quite extensive access (read access for all users).

Comment: I had the same issue for a couple of days. Since I was trying to access the database through Apache, I added `www-data` to the group and gave it the required permissions. It worked. But then I realised that it only works the first time after I have given it the permissions, then it reverts back to the original permissions. So I had to make `www-data` the owner

Comment: I think 770 for db and 660 for containing directories is enough.