# "no such table: Sport" on exporting a table from sqlite db (django view)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views, export-to-csv

In my django view, after updating a table, I put this code for exporting that table into csv file:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import os
import csv

# export Data
print ("Export data into csv file..............")
conn = sql.connect('sqlite3.db') #  I tried: db.sqlite3 -> same
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from Sport")
with open("heartrateai_data.csv", "w") as csv_file:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter="\t")
     csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
     csv_writer.writerows(cursor)
dirpath = os.getcwdb()+"/heartrateai_data.csv"
print("Data exported Successfully into {}".format(dirpath))
conn.close()
```

But it gives me the error: **Exception Value:   no such table: Sport**.
I am sure that the table name is correct because is the same in my model.py.

I am not sure if it correct the line with connection and connection close. I am new in this.
My browser: [image]

Edit 2:
I saw that the correct way to write the path is with 'E:\...' or with r'E:...'. I wrote like this in my code `conn = sql.connect(r'E:\Work\django\analysisData\db.sqlite3')` but I have the same error. "No such table: Sport"

Comment: To be clear: is it a db stored in a file named 'sqlite3.db' in the same folder as the script? And `sql` is the alias for the `sqlite3` package?

Comment: Yes, I edit the post and write the lines for import. And for the first question: I have the db in the big project, but not in the folder that I write that code. (I attached an image with what I have in browser.  the code is wrote in the csvFile/view.py). I know that is not the same name in the code with the name of the db from browser. I tried both to be sure that I didn't wrote something bad.

Comment: The problem is `sqlite3` does not fail if the database you connect to does not exist. It just creates the file. If you navigate to the path of the script you will probably find the ones it created.  I believe you should put the correct path to it, something like `../../db.sqlite3` (depending where the db is stored with respect to the Django view). Maybe show the complete folder structure with both the script and the db.

Comment: If I write : ```conn = sql.connect('E:\Work\django\analysisData\db.sqlite3')```, it gives me the error: Unable to open database file.  And If I put: ```conn = sql.connect('E:/Work/django/analysisData/db.sqlite3')``` -> no such table: Sport

Comment: I believe there is a permission issue, i.e. sqlite3 does not have the permission to read/write the file. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886737/2246849)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I wrote this lines in my code:

```
con = sql.connect(r'E:\Work\django\analysisData\db.sqlite3')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

I saw that the name of the table isn't the same like in the model.py. The name of tables is: projectName_NameOfTable.
I modified the table name, and I don't have that error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> python manage.py makemigrations

> python manage.py migrate

it can be just Django's error

Comment: I did this. I delete all my migrations, everything, I wrote that commands but nothing has changed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).